# Convert System.Web.HttpContext.Current to System.Web.HttpContextBase

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to access the OwinContext from within a constructor of one of my controllers, like so:

```
protected SEMController()
{
    var currentUserIsAdmin = false;
    var currentUserName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User?.Identity?.Name;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUserName))
    {
        var user = UserManager.Users
            .SingleOrDefault(u => 
            u.UserName.Equals(currentUserName, 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (user != null)
        {
            currentUserIsAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, UserType.Admin);
        }
    }
    TempData["CurrentUserIsAdmin"] = currentUserIsAdmin;
}
```

where the `UserManager` is a property of the same controller and it looks like this:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        if (_userManager == null)
        {
            _userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        return _userManager;
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

However, at the time the code is in the ctor, the `HttpContext`, which is a property of the `Controller` class and is of type `System.Web.HttpContextBase` and is not a `System.Web.HttpContext` instance, is null.

But since anyway the ASP.NET framework simply copies information from one place to another, the information they will have , at some point later in time, will be the same.

So, I was wondering if I could get a reference to the `OwinContext` by directly using the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` property. However, that property is of type `System.Web.HttpContext` where as the `GetOwinContext` is an extension method on the type `System.Web.HttpContextBase` and I see that these two classes are no way related to each other.

So, I was wondering if there was a way to get from `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` to `System.Web.HttpContextBase`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
HttpContextBase httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
```

And yes, the `HttpContext` property is always null during the construction of controllers. You can use it safely in (and after) the [`Controller.Initialize` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize(v=vs.118).aspx).

> Initializes data that might not be available when the constructor is called.